# Find YouTube channels with around 300 subscribers

Tags: youtube

How can I find YouTube channels (German ones) with around 300 subscribers (yes only around 300)?

Is there a way to search in YouTube for subscriber counts like this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters a list of every single search parameter built into youtube and not one includes subscriber count. Sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on YouTube itself; as of now, the site simply doesn't support it. As always, if you want a feature on YouTube, make sure you send feedback (usually at the bottom of the page or at the bottom of the sidebar).

You didn't specify why you want to find German channels with 300 subscribers in your initial post, but I'm assuming it's got to do with you making a collaboration with them. If so, YouTube does have a platform to find collaboration partners now, [even in German](https://www.youtube-creatorcommunity.com/t5/Creator-Community/ct-p/DE_Creator-Community). It's currently in 1.0 status (ie: works, but is pretty bare-bones) and not advertised by them that much though.